# как сделать буквы маленькими из класса enum при выводе в консоли

Tags: java, eclipse

Car prius = new PassengerCar("Toyota Prius", 15000, 2008, 1200, Color.GREEN);

System.out.println(prius);

Car [name=Toyota Prius, yearOfProduction=15000, price=2008, weight=1200, color=GREEN, distance=0.0, distanceOnService=0.0]

Comment: Переопределите `toString()` в Car или Color

Comment: toString() переопределен в Car но не помогает, выводит заглавные

Comment: Значит вынеправильно переопределили. Надо в нем например перевести нужное значение в нижний регистр

Comment: Спасибо огромное помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевести имя перечисление в нижний регистр.  System.out.println(Color.GREEN.name().toLowerCase());

Comment: Спасибо, помогло